# How do I pin the Python version for a project?

Tags: python, requirements.txt

I understand that the standard way of communicating package depencencies for a Python project is the `requirements.txt` file. But is there a standard way of communicating the Python version to other developers?

In my case, the project uses 3.9 features so it cannot be older than that. Also, 3.10 causes mysterious problems in combination with some packages so I want to exclude it as well.

Comment: I don't think the good ol' pip requirements.txt will do this; but more modern tools like https://python-poetry.org will.

Comment: We use install scripts, to make sure everyone is set up in the same way - this has the python version pinned. I guess you could detect if the python version is not as expected, and throw a warning in your "main" program: `if sys.version_info[:3] != (3,8,1): ...`. Alternatively if you're into docker, you could create an image with the dependencies preinstalled.